# Issue about iteration of my jquery element

Tags: javascript, jquery, iteration

I'm customizing the date range picker

- npm link [ngx-daterangepicker-material](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-daterangepicker-material)
- github link [ngx-daterangepicker-material](https://github.com/fetrarij/ngx-daterangepicker-material)

I would like to iterate my jquery element to customize it , the problem is when i iterate it and apply some modification to an element of this iteration it doesn't do it on the right element. Seems it's making an memory conflict.

I want to get the text of the case to apply or not a background color but seems there is a difference when it go in the if and when it apply the style to the element.

Because seems like there is a 3 case differences between the if and the style

```
for(let i = 0;$('.md-drppicker .calendar-table .table-condensed tbody tr td').length != i; i++) {
      if($('.md-drppicker .calendar-table .table-condensed tbody tr td')[i].textContent > diff &&
       $('.md-drppicker .calendar-table .table-condensed tbody tr td')[i].textContent < begin) {
        $('.md-drppicker .calendar-table .table-condensed tbody tr td')[i].classList.add("in-range");
        $('.md-drppicker .calendar-table .table-condensed tbody tr td')[i].setAttribute( 'style', 'background-color :red!important');
      }
      else if($('.md-drppicker .calendar-table .table-condensed tbody tr td')[i].textContent == diff) {
        $('.md-drppicker .calendar-table .table-condensed tbody tr td')[i].classList.add("start-date");
        $('.md-drppicker .calendar-table .table-condensed tbody tr td')[i].classList.add("active");
        $('.md-drppicker .calendar-table .table-condensed tbody tr td')[i].setAttribute( 'style', 'background-color :red!important');
      }
      else if($('.md-drppicker .calendar-table .table-condensed tbody tr td')[i].textContent == begin) {
        $('.md-drppicker .calendar-table .table-condensed tbody tr td')[i].classList.add("end-date");
        $('.md-drppicker .calendar-table .table-condensed tbody tr td')[i].classList.add("active");
        $('.md-drppicker .calendar-table .table-condensed tbody tr td')[i].setAttribute( 'style', 'background-color :red!important');
      }
    }
```

The Jquery element is looking like this :

```
0: td.weekend.off.available
1: td.off.available
2: td.off.available
3: td.off.available
4: td.off.available
5: td.available
6: td.weekend.available
...
```

Do i iterate correctly my element ?
Thanks

Comment: I removed the [tag:angular] tag, this has nothing to do with [angular](https://angular.io)

Comment: Your code would be easier to read and modify if you put this as the 1st line inside the `for` block: `var element = $('.md-drppicker .calendar-table .table-condensed tbody tr td')[i];` and then used this on all subsequent lines inside the `for` block.

Comment: why not use $('.md-drppicker .calendar-table .table-condensed tbody tr td').each

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "iterate correctly", because you have multiple ways to iterate over a jQuery collection. Some do make more sense than others, though. If you want to know if you use an *efficient* or *elegant* way, then the answer is "No".

To improve readability as well as performance, query the DOM a *single* time instead of multiple times with the exact same selector and store the result in a binding. Every time you write `$( [[SELECTOR]] )`, jQuery runs through the complete DOM and matches nodes agains the selector you pass into it.

Also, you could use the `.each` method of the jQuery collection instead of a loop (see @Jayruben's comment). It makes your code *easier to understand* than using a loop, because it iterates over each element by default in order. Also, you don't have to grab the element by hand via the bracket operator.

I'm not sure which values the `diff` and `begin` variables contain, but it *looks* as if you try to compare a `String` (the value of `textContent`) with `Number` or `Date` values. That's very likely to fail. Instead, parse all values to the *same* type. Given you want to alter a *Datepicker*, it's likely you have to convert all values to `Date` objects. However, as said, since I don't know where `diff` and `begin` come from nor what they contain, this is just a guess.

Here's what your code might look like after the changes I described (except the parsing):

```
let $td = $('.md-drppicker .calendar-table .table-condensed tbody tr td')
$td.each(function () {
  let text = this.textContent; // "this" points to the current <td> element
  if (text > diff && text < begin) {
    this.classList.add('in-range');
    this.style.backgroundColor = 'red !important';
    return; // return early, avoids if () else if () else nesting/chaining
  }
  if (text === diff) {
    this.classList.add('start-date');
    this.classList.add('active');
    this.style.backgroundColor = 'red !important';
    return;
  }
  if (text === begin) {
    this.classList.add('end-date');
    this.classList.add('active');
    this.style.backgroundColor = 'red !important');
    // last if, no return needed
  }
});
```

**EDIT**

You can also do it with a loop, but it's a bit more "messy", because of the nitty-gritty *extra variables* the loop uses. Anyway, here is the loop based version:

```
let $td = $('.md-drppicker .calendar-table .table-condensed tbody tr td')
for (let $tdIndex = 0; $tdIndex < $td.length; $tdIndex += 1) {
  let elem = $td[$tdIndex];
  let text = elem.textContent;

  if (text > diff && text < begin) {
    elem.classList.add('in-range');
    elem.style.backgroundColor = 'red !important';
    continue; // jump to next iteration
  }
  if (text === diff) {
    elem.classList.add('start-date');
    elem.classList.add('active');
    elem.style.backgroundColor = 'red !important';
    continue;
  }
  if (text === begin) {
    elem.classList.add('end-date');
    elem.classList.add('active');
    elem.style.backgroundColor = 'red !important');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man it's working much more better ! The variables are Number, to callback the selector was really not good maybe cause of it I had this issue. Thanks again for you time :)

Comment: @BaptisteGoudey No probs, glad I could help. Please accept the answer if it solved your problem, this way you can "help me" :) By the way: If you want to parse the `textContent` to a `Number`, you usually use `parseInt`, `parseFloat` or simply the `Number` constructor as a "normal" function call. For example: `let text = Number(this.textContent)` (or `let text = parseInt(this.textContent, 10)`).

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to do it with a for ? cause i should compare with next element 
When i try to use 'for' there is a lot of missing elements when i iterate

Comment: @BaptisteGoudey Updated my answer to include an example using a `for` loop

Comment: Works perfectly ! Thanks u !